# Get the absolute path of an executable from $PATH with Java

Tags: java, node.js, java-io

I am calling a nodeJS executable in my command line Java app. Because the executable is in a location in the `$PATH` variable, in can just simply call it as `node`. However, I must then provide a parameter (the .js file to run) which if I provide as a relative path to the `node` executable, nodeJS throws an error that it can't find the .js file.

So, what I'm looking for is to get the absolute path of the `node` executable that is being run and then compile the absolute path of the .js file I must add as parameter to the `node` command.

Is there a way of doing that in Java that is platform-agnostic? I realize I can run `where node`, get the output and go from there, but I wouldn't want to hardcode OS-specific commands.

Here's my code so far:

```
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("node");
    cmdLine.addArgument("D:/SDKs/Appium/node_modules/appium/lib/server/main.js");
    cmdLine.addArgument("--address");
    cmdLine.addArgument("0.0.0.0");
    cmdLine.addArgument("--port");
    cmdLine.addArgument("4444");
    cmdLine.addArgument("--app");
    File app = new File("some.apk");
    cmdLine.addArgument(app.getAbsolutePath());
    cmdLine.addArgument("--app-pkg");
    cmdLine.addArgument("some.stuff.does.not.matter");
    cmdLine.addArgument("--pre-launch");
    cmdLine.addArgument("--automation-name");
    cmdLine.addArgument("Appium");
    System.out.println(cmdLine.toString());
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(60000);
    executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
    try {
        int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error starting Appium: " + e.getMessage());
```

Notice the part with `D:/SDKs/Appium/node_modules/appium/lib/server/main.js`? I need to build that in an intelligent way in order to remove the hardcoding.

Answer (score 1):

You have to scan the $PATH for yourself.
Here's the [demo](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/61023aced57a022706f9a3455034e9ba) (hosted on github)

The key point is:

```
System.getenv("PATH")
      .split(System.getProperty("path.separator"))
```

The rest is simple for over each path and searching for a file called "node".

Comment: The .js file is in the nodeJS directory, not in my Java project directory, which I do not know where it is. That's why I need to get the node executable's location. Therefore, I can't just instantiate the .js as a file. If I would have known where it is, it would have been easy.

Comment: I see you've updated your answer, but you still haven't gotten the point. I don't know where the .js file is, I just know where it is related to the `node` executable location. I can't instance it in a `File` object.

Comment: Maybe the correct answer has to do with *$PATH*.
The tools *which* and *where* just scan the *$PATH* for an executable with that name. That is something that you could do as well.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like it. But how do I know which folder in $PATH my executable belongs to? $PATH usually stores multiple locations separated by semicolons or something.